# getClipboard Content in Overlay Service not working on new Android version. Alternative?

Tags: android-studio, overlay, clipboard, android-10.0

I have an App that uses a floating overlay over other apps with a Search function.
Basic User Story is to copy a text to the clipboard, click on Overlay, and search for text in Clipboard.

this worked for a long time no Problem but with Android 10 it only works if the App is in the foreground.
If another App like Chrome is in the foreground the clipboard.getPrimaryClip() returns only a null pointer.

I guess they changed some permissions in Android. I searched on google and co but I didn't find any clues.

Is there an alternative way to get the Clipboard content event when I'm not in the App the overlay comes from? This kinda breaks the whole idea of that feature.

Technical Info: I'm extending the Service class and a WindowManager like this:

```
mWindowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
```

this is how I get the clipboard text:

```
public String getClipboardText()
{
    try {
        ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
        if (clipboard.getPrimaryClip().getItemCount() > 0) {
            return clipboard.getPrimaryClip().getItemAt(0).getText().toString();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems Android 10 changes privacy settings and there is no alternative way to access the clipboard text. its also not possible to request permission, because clipboard permission given by "READ_LOGS" permission is only allowed for system apps.